# No Pooling approach is being applied from a fixed effect

Tags: terminology, pooling

Hello I was reading about no pooling and partial pooling.

I understoond that a mixed model is using partial pooling approach when we talking about hierarchical data.

Is it correct to say that fixed effect model is using no pooling approach?